# How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, duplicate-data

How can I remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Example array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => def
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ghi
        [1] => jkl
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => mno
        [1] => pql
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => def
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => ghi
        [1] => jkl
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => mno
        [1] => pql
    )

)
```

Comment: This question does not have a [mcve]. We have input, but no expression of the exact desired output.  This leads to divergent answers that respect both columns for uniqueness or respect only one of the columns for uniqueness.

Comment: See [Filter/Remove rows where column value is found more than once in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604306/2943403) for a comprehensive list of techniques accommodating different scenarios with nuanced behavior.

Answer (score 737, accepted):

Here is another way. No intermediate variables are saved.

We used this to de-duplicate results from a variety of overlapping queries.

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Comment: Because of unserialize this is slower and slower the larger and more complex the array is. There is a reason I used array_intersect_key (half a year before this answer).

Comment: @OIS they wanted a one liner i guess. should have just rewritten as $no-duplicates = array_intersect_key( $array , array_unique( array_map('serialize') , $array ) );

Comment: @OIS well just tested it, had a typo but it works.. thanks dude!: $no_duplicates = array_intersect_key( $array , array_unique( array_map('serialize' , $array ) ) );

Comment: if you want the index continuous, use array_values i.e. $input = array_values(array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input))));

Comment: Nowadays you probably would opt for json_encode and json_decode instead of PHP serialization. should have benefits for the values provided *and* you don't run into PHP serialization details that serialize/unserialize ships with and most likely are unwanted.

Comment: $input = array_values($input); To fix missing array keys inside the array

Comment: Although cool I don't want to depend on `serialize` and `unserialize`. The way PHP has implemented these has changed behind the scenes a few times. For the longest time references was not stored. They are now, but only to references within the serialized array. (I know the question didn't have objects). The better way would be `array_unique($input, SORT_REGULAR)` or some custom function.

Comment: Beware that `serialize(array('a' => '1', 'b' => '1'))` is different from `serialize(array('b' => '1', 'a' => '1'))`. This option will fail for arrays used as `sets` or `(hash)maps`.

Comment: Even better with single commas!

`$input = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $input)));`

Comment: @Michael - From the current PHP doc: "Note that **array_unique()** is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays."

Comment: Good answer but it does not support entries with different order like [['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'foo']]. To use your snippet, I sorted the child arrays.

Comment: @dave when you don't include an explanation with your snippet, the page suffers from receiving [an exact duplicate snippet which INCLUDES an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39270353/2943403).  You could have prevented this by explaining your answer.

Answer (score 315):

Since 5.2.9 you can use [`array_unique()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) if you use the `SORT_REGULAR` flag like so:

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

This makes the function compare elements for equality as if `$a == $b` were being used, which is perfect for your case.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => def
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ghi
            [1] => jkl
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => mno
            [1] => pql
        )

)
```

Keep in mind, though, that [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#refsect1-function.array-unique-notes) states:

> `array_unique()` is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: I guess this is more quick and more clear solution, than the accepted one! lets vote for this one! :) Hmmm [on php site](http://php.net/array_unique#98453) we can see that it is not so quick, as I thought...

Comment: Strange that using the SORT_REGULAR flag just doesn't work for me, to remove duplicate arrays.

Comment: @Stefan then you may wish to consider asking a new question.

Comment: There are already other, working answers to this question which I have verified (see for example the accepted answer).  I just cannot verify this particular answer, for my particular example.

Comment: @Stefan could you provide a pastebin for your particular issue then? Just telling me it doesn't work is not helping me understand.

Comment: @Stefan You're right; it doesn't seem to give the correct results, but it's probably a bug because it [works with PHP 7](http://3v4l.org/qESFP) =/

Comment: Very interesting... Thank you very much Jack, for your attention to this - amazing response.  Anyway, since I cannot change the php version on the server I will just have to use one of the other solutions.

Comment: This also appears to work in my case but is anybody else bothered by this note in the array_unique() doc? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#refsect1-function.array-unique-notes

Comment: @Jack You're right this is a bug as of PHP 5.6.23: https://eval.in/645675 but is fixed as of PHP 7.0.8: https://eval.in/645676

Comment: Beware `array(1, 2)` is different from `array(2, 1)`. This will fail for arrays used as `sets`.

Comment: @AndrasGyomrey if you want to express sets with arrays you should normalise them.

Comment: Either you use `in_array` or you make sure your elements are usable as array keys (serializable) and you use some dummy array value. It depends on your implementation. For the first implementation, you can't go with this approach.

Comment: This is proper solution compared to serialize/unserialize answer. Please note, that array unique is rather fast compared to serialize/deserialize. This *might* be issue if you do hundreds/thousands of array unique.

Comment: Note this causes strange behavior with assoc arrays that have boolean true values (those disappear). Example: https://3v4l.org/Yj6Y1 (`show_in_configurator` disappeared).

Answer (score 70):

Another way. Will preserve keys as well.

```
function array_unique_multidimensional($input)
{
    $serialized = array_map('serialize', $input);
    $unique = array_unique($serialized);
    return array_intersect_key($input, $unique);
}
```

Comment: For large arrays, this method is often at least 50% faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 68):

I had a similar problem but I found a 100% working solution for it.

```
<?php
    function super_unique($array,$key)
    {
       $temp_array = [];
       foreach ($array as &$v) {
           if (!isset($temp_array[$v[$key]]))
           $temp_array[$v[$key]] =& $v;
       }
       $array = array_values($temp_array);
       return $array;

    }


$arr="";
$arr[0]['id']=0;
$arr[0]['titel']="ABC";
$arr[1]['id']=1;
$arr[1]['titel']="DEF";
$arr[2]['id']=2;
$arr[2]['titel']="ABC";
$arr[3]['id']=3;
$arr[3]['titel']="XYZ";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "unique*********************<br/>";
print_r(super_unique($arr,'titel'));

?>
```

Comment: This answers a different question. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585208/how-can-you-make-a-multidimensional-array-unique

Comment: Great function! and in case you're dealing with objects:
            if(!isset($array->$v->$key)) $array[$v->$key] =& $v;

Comment: The modification by reference in this answer is entirely unnecessary.  I agree with OIS, this answer is not respecting both columns when determining uniqueness.  This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 55):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => john
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => smith
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => john
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => robert
        )

)

$temp = array_unique(array_column($array, 'name'));
$unique_arr = array_intersect_key($array, $temp);
```

This will remove the duplicate names from array. unique by key

Comment: Make sure that `$array`'s keys start at "0". It's possible `$array`'s keys start at another number if `$array` is the result of a prior array manipulation. Use `array_values` to reset the keys back to "0"

Comment: This answer is not respecting both columns when determining uniqueness.  This is the correct answer to a different question.

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

If "remove duplicates" means "remove duplicates, but let one there", a solution might be to apply the `array_unique(...)` on the "identifier column" first and then to remove in the original array all the keys, that have been removed from the column array:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => '123',
        'foo' => 'aaa',
        'bar' => 'bbb'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '123',
        'foo' => 'ccc',
        'bar' => 'ddd'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '567',
        'foo' => 'eee',
        'bar' => 'fff'
    ]
];

$ids = array_column($array, 'id');
$ids = array_unique($ids);
$array = array_filter($array, function ($key, $value) use ($ids) {
    return in_array($value, array_keys($ids));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [foo] => aaa
            [bar] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 567
            [foo] => eee
            [bar] => fff
        )

)
```

Comment: This answer is not respecting both columns when determining uniqueness.  This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 22):

The user comments on the [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) documentation have many solutions to this. Here is one of them:

> **kenrbnsn at rbnsn dot com**
> 27-Sep-2005 12:09

> Yet another Array_Unique for multi-demensioned arrays. I've only tested this on two-demensioned arrays, but it could probably be generalized for more, or made to use recursion.

> This function uses the serialize, array_unique, and unserialize functions to do the work.

> 

function multi_unique($array) {
foreach ($array as $k=>$na)
$new[$k] = serialize($na);
$uniq = array_unique($new);
foreach($uniq as $k=>$ser)
$new1[$k] = unserialize($ser);
return ($new1);
}

This is from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#57202.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to eliminate duplicates on specific keys, such as a mysqli id, here's a simple funciton

```
function search_array_compact($data,$key){
    $compact = [];
    foreach($data as $row){
        if(!in_array($row[$key],$compact)){
            $compact[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $compact;
}
```

**Bonus Points**
You can pass an array of keys and add an outer foreach, but it will be 2x slower per additional key.

Comment: Iterated calls of `in_array()` will be one of the worst possible performer on this whole page.  `!in_array()` has a big O of `n`, therefore we are looking at `O(n * n)` -- no bueno.

Comment: @mickmackusa fair points, thanks for the feedback. i will try to think of a more efficient solution

Answer (score 2):

if you have an array like this:

(users is the name of the array)

```
Array=>
 [0] => (array)
   'user' => 'john'
   'age' => '23'
 [1] => (array)
  'user' => 'jane'
  'age' => '20'
 [2]=> (array)
  'user' => 'john'
  'age' => '23'
```

and you want to delete duplicates...then:

```
$serialized = array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($users); $i++) { 
  $test = in_array($users['user'], $serialized);
    if ($test == false) {
      $serialized[] = $users['user'];
    }
 }
```

can be a solution :P

Comment: This answer doesn't respect both columns when determining uniqueness. Iterated calls of `in_array()` will be one of the worst possible performer on this whole page.  `!in_array()` has a big O of `n`, therefore we are looking at `O(n * n)` -- no bueno.  This answer is merely r3wt's answer written with an unnecessary, single-use variable (`$test`).

Answer (score 2):

Lots of person asked me how to make Unique multidimensional array. I have taken reference from your comment and it helps me.

First of All, Thanks to @jeromegamez @daveilers for your solution. But every time i gave the answer, they asked me how this 'serialize' and 'unserialize' works. That's why i want to share the reason of this with you so that it will help more people to understand the concept behind this.

I am explaining why we use 'serialize' and 'unserialize' in steps :

**Step 1: Convert the multidimensional array to one-dimensional array**

To convert the multidimensional array to a one-dimensional array, first generate byte stream representation of all the elements (including nested arrays) inside the array. serialize() function can generate byte stream representation of a value. To generate byte stream representation of all the elements, call serialize() function inside array_map() function as a callback function. The result will be a one dimensional array no matter how many levels the multidimensional array has.

**Step 2: Make the values unique**

To make this one dimensional array unique, use array_unique() function.

**Step 3: Revert it to the multidimensional array**

Though the array is now unique, the values looks like byte stream representation. To revert it back to the multidimensional array, use unserialize() function.

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Thanks again for all this.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy and logical way to Unique a multi dimension array is as follows,

If you have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [Key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value1
            [1] => Value2
            [2] => Value1
            [3] => Value3
            [4] => Value1
        )
    [Key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value1
            [1] => Value2
            [2] => Value1
            [3] => Value3
            [4] => Value4
        )
)
```

use `foreach` to solve this:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $unique=array_unique($v);
    $array[$k]=$unique;
}
```

it will give you following result:

```
Array
(
    [Key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value1
            [1] => Value2
            [3] => Value3
        )
    [Key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value1
            [1] => Value2
            [3] => Value3
            [4] => Value4
        )
)
```

and if you want to rearrange the order of the keys,

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $unique= array_values(array_unique($v));
    $array[$k]=$unique;
}
```

This operation will give you arranged key values like this:

```
Array
(
    [Key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value1
            [1] => Value2
            [2] => Value3
        )
    [Key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Value1
            [1] => Value2
            [2] => Value3
            [3] => Value4
        )
)
```

I hope this will clear everything.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the asker's sample data and deviates WAAAAAAY beyond the scope of this question.  I'd argue that this answer doesn't get close to answering the question asked.  The asker is not seeking a way to remove duplicate values within each subarray.

Answer (score 1):

An easy to read solution, probably not the most efficient:

```
function arrayUnique($myArray){
    if(!is_array($myArray))
        return $myArray;

    foreach ($myArray as &$myvalue){
        $myvalue=serialize($myvalue);
    }

    $myArray=array_unique($myArray);

    foreach ($myArray as &$myvalue){
        $myvalue=unserialize($myvalue);
    }

    return $myArray;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As people are saying `array_unique()` is very slow, here is a snippet I use for one level multidimensional array.

```
$serialized_array = array_map("serialize", $input);

foreach ($serialized_array as $key => $val) {
     $result[$val] = true;
}

$output = array_map("unserialize", (array_keys($result)));
```

Reference first user contributed note of `array_unique()` [function page in php.net](http://php.net/array_unique)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is relevant only when uniqueness is needed for one array column, for example here if we need the uniqueness in index #0 of the arrays.

Solution #1:

Using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and a [static variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static):

```
<?php

$list = [
    ['abc', 'def'],
    ['ghi', 'jkl'],
    ['mno', 'pql'],
    ['abc', 'def'],
    ['ghi', 'jkl'],
    ['mno', 'pql']
];

$list = array_filter($list, function ($item) {
    static $values = [];
    if (!in_array($item[0], $values)) {
        $values[] = $item[0];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

var_dump($list);
```

Solution #2:

Since the value when we want the uniqueness are of string type, we can remap the original global array to use these values as keys, which will remove duplicates as we remap it:

```
<?php

$list = [
    ['abc', 'def'],
    ['ghi', 'jkl'],
    ['mno', 'pql'],
    ['abc', 'def'],
    ['ghi', 'jkl'],
    ['mno', 'pql']
];

$unique = [];

foreach ($list as $item) {
    $unique[$item[0]] = $item;
}

// Remap again to integers
$unique = array_values($unique);

var_dump($unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to serialize and unique

```
$test = [
    ['abc','def'],
    ['ghi','jkl'],
    ['mno','pql'],
    ['abc','def'],
    ['ghi','jkl'],
    ['mno','pql'],
];

$result = array_reduce(
    $test,
    function($carry,$item){
        if(!in_array($item,$carry)) {
            array_push($carry,$item);
        }
        return $carry;
    },
    []
);

var_dump($result);

/*
 php unique.php
array(3) {
    [0] =>
        array(2) {
            [0] =>
                string(3) "abc"
            [1] =>
                string(3) "def"
        }
    [1] =>
        array(2) {
            [0] =>
                string(3) "ghi"
            [1] =>
                string(3) "jkl"
        }
    [2] =>
        array(2) {
              [0] =>
                  string(3) "mno"
              [1] =>
                  string(3) "pql"
        }
}
```

*/

Comment: Iterated calls of `!in_array()` will suffer exponentially worse performance as the size of the input array increases.

Answer (score 0):

I've given this problem a lot of thought and have determined that the optimal solution should follow two rules.

1. For scalability, modify the array in place; no copying to a new array
2. For performance, each comparison should be made only once

With that in mind and given all of PHP's quirks, below is the solution I came up with. Unlike some of the other answers, it has the ability to remove elements based on whatever key(s) you want. The input array is expected to be numeric keys.

```
$count_array = count($input);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_array; $i++) {
    if (isset($input[$i])) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < $count_array; $j++) {
            if (isset($input[$j])) {
                //this is where you do your comparison for dupes
                if ($input[$i]['checksum'] == $input[$j]['checksum']) {
                    unset($input[$j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only drawback is that the keys are not in order when the iteration completes. This isn't a problem if you're subsequently using only foreach loops, but if you need to use a for loop, you can put `$input = array_values($input);` after the above to renumber the keys.

Comment: There is no performance boost to your nested, conditional `unset()` calls because you are making value comparisons instead of key comparison (which PHP performs much faster with).

Answer (score 0):

try this solution for **(n)** Dimensional array with **non-restricted length**
for example this array

```
$arr= [
0 => [0=>"a" , 1=>"b" ,  2=>"c" ] ,
1 => [0=>"x" , 1=>"b" , 2=>"a", 3=>"p"],
2=>   [
       [ 
          0=>"y" ,
          1=>"b" ,
          2=> [0=>"x" , 1=>"m" , 2=>"a"]
       ],
       1=>"z" ,
       2=>"v"
       ]
     ];
```

This would be the solution

```
$ar2=[];
$ar3=[];
function test($arr){
    
    global $ar2,$ar3;
    if(is_array($arr)){
       return array_map("test",$arr);
    }
    if(!isset($ar2[$arr])){
        $ar2[$arr]=1;
        $ar3[]=$arr;
    }
}
array_map("test",$arr);
print_r($ar3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the Answer marked as correct, adding my answer. Small code added just to reset the indices-

```
$input = array_values(array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $inputArray))));
```

Comment: @milic's answer from 6 years earlier shows how to wrap the nested function calls with `array_values()`.  I don't see the need to add this answer.  You could have just added a comment under the accepted answer to say "if you want to re-index the result, just call `array_values()`".